# How to create folders based on file names and then move them to the folders

Tags: batch-file, copy, directory, move

I want a batch to create folders automatically based on zip files.

The zip files have different names and I want to create folders automatically with the same name as those files and move them all there.

Example:

**I have these files:**

```
[Jungle] part 1.zip
[Jungle] part 2.zip
[Jungle] part 3.zip
[People] Of babies.zip
[People] Of people.zip
[Animals] From the sea.zip
[Animals] Furry.zip
```

- All the files that contain "[Jungle]" create a folder called "Jungle"
  and they are moved there.
- All files that contain "[People]" create a folder called "People" and
  are moved there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on pattern of `[folder] etc.zip`.

```
@echo off
setlocal

for %%A in ("[*]*.zip") do call :movefile "%%~A"
goto :eof

:movefile
setlocal
for /f "delims=]" %%A in ("%~1") do (set "folder=%%~A") & goto :next
:next
set "folder=%folder:~1%"
if not exist "%folder%" md "%folder%"
move "%~1" "%folder%"
goto :eof
```

The `for` loop searches for files matching pattern of `[*]*.zip`
and calls the `:movefile` label on each file found. The filename
is passed as an argument to the first argument of `%1`.
`%~1` strips outer quotes so it can be placed in new outer quotes.
The `for` loop in the :movefile label delimits the `"%~1"` string by the
character `]`. The variable `folder` will be set the 1st token.
`goto :next` ensures only one loop is done.
`%folder:~1%` is the value of `%folder%` without the 1st character of `[`.
The folder is created if not exist and then the file is moved into the folder.

Comment: why not just `"delims=[]"`? Would eliminate the need for a variable (and so the need of delayed expansion)

Comment: @Stephan, I chose to delimit on `]` and remove the 1st character so the code operates only on start of the string. Delimit on `[]` could delimit not on the start of string if the 1st `for` loop has the pattern changed. I wanted to avoid working within the 2nd `for` loop in which I would need delayed expansion and so the variable `folder` informs the questionnaire that it is the actual folder name. I may do it different next time just by choice.